# How to use html in asp classic email object body?

Tags: html, email, asp-classic, html-email

I want to use html in my email body in my classic asp code. This is code:

```
Dim objCDO
Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
objCDO.To = "rydsouza@osler.com"
objCDO.From = "oslernet@osler.com"
objCDO.Subject = "Test Subject"
objCDO.Body = "<html><head></head><body><b>There has been a change.</b></body></html>"
objCDO.Send
```

However when I view the email, the body looks exactly like this string, with all the tags. I want the tags to be rendered and make the text bold.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CDONTS then you need to add another couple of parameters to your object

```
objCDO.BodyFormat=0
objCDO.MailFormat=0
```

See this link 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189945

That said, CDOSYS was introduced on Win 2000 and CDONTS was removed completely from Win 2003, so I recommend you use CDOSYS, (unless you're on a really old NT box).  Creating HTML emails is also rather easier

The w3schools tutorial is quite good
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp